# If $a^{p}\cdot b^{p}= (a\cdot b)^{p}$ then why $-1^{2}\cdot 3^{2}\neq (-1\cdot 3)^{2}$

Tags: exponentiation

If $a^{p}\cdot b^{p}= (a\cdot b)^{p}$ then why 
$$-1^{2}\cdot 3^{2}\neq  (-1\cdot 3)^{2}\\
-1\cdot 9\neq (-3)^{2}\\
-9\neq 9$$

I'm sorry, I don't know how to put latex code.

Comment: You presumably mean $a^2\cdot b^2=(a\cdot b)^2$?

Comment: There is a difference between $(-1)^2$ and $-1^2$, when you plug in a value you technically need parentheses, but normally it doesnt matter, when it is a negatice value however, it does matter

Comment: @nosyarg I didn't know that, is that a rule? if so, could you tell me where to find it so I can read about it?

Comment: This is the page of a math teacher who wrote about it:     http://www.angrymath.com/2014/08/when-are-parentheses-required-for.html?m=1

Comment: Thank you, @nosyarg, a very interesting read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because if $a=-1$ then $a^2=(-1)^2\neq -(1^2)$. Yo are treating $a^2=-(1^2)$, which is wrong.

Comment: But -1^2 is -1, what if a were -1?

Comment: Umm, did you even read my answer? It's all about if $a=-1$. @Jose

Comment: I did, but I don't understand why if a is -1 why $a^2=(-1)^2$ and not $a^2=-1^2=-1$ I mean, sure I could put -1 in brackets, raise it to the power of 2 and it would give me just 1. But my question is much like $-2^2=-4$ as opposed to $(-2)^2=4$

Comment: $a^2=a\cdot a = (-1)\cdot (-1)$. Sorry if you don't understand how parentheses work, but $a^2$ is multiplying the number by itself. You get two minus signs, not one. Substitution isn't in a vacuum. If $a=2+3$ then $3\cdot a\neq 3\cdot 2+3=9$. Rather $3\cdot a=3\cdot (2+3)$. When we substitute, we often add parens because otherwise we get ambiguities.

Comment: @Jose: I am assuming here that $p$ is prime correct? The way you are going about this is $-1^2 = -(1)^2 = -1^{1}$. Now do you see why this doesn't hold? The exponent $1 \not \in \{\textbf{primes}\}$.

Comment: @Mr.Fry In this question $p=2$. All other questions about $p$ are irrelevant.

Comment: If $a=1+1$ is $a^2=1+1^2=1+1=2$? @Jose No, $a^2=(1+1)^2$. See, we've again added parentheses when making a substitution.

Comment: Basically, you are suggesting that $a^2\neq (a)^2$ for some values of $a$. That is going to make mathematics nonsensical. @Jose

Comment: @ThomasAndrews. Yes. Please ready what I wrote carefully. I am showing that the way he is treating the exponent is equivalent to my comment. And I was suggesting that typically when someone uses $p$ it means prime. So as the statement stands it is relevant because this is what I use to draw a contradiction.

Comment: There is no reason at all to believe he wants $p$ is prime, rather than being just a variable for "power," considering the nature of his question. @Mr.Fry And it really does not affect his question at all, except for that we probably want $p$ to be an integer.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, that is what I'm suggesting, I should have been clearer in expressing myself. I know it makes it nosensical to "defy" rules, but it's fun, just like trying to prove that 1+1 doesn't equal 2. I appreciate your input.

Comment: @Mr.Fry That's not what I meant, as Thomas said, p is just a variable for power, but what you said is really interesting too, so I thank you for bringing that up, more stuff to think about is always good :p

Answer (score 1):

You are wrong here.

$a^{p} b^{p}=(ab)^{p}$

And your math on that example is wrong. You forgot the brackets.

$(-1)^2(3)^2=(-3)^2=+9$.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. But I didn't forget the brackets, considering -1^2 is -1 (not (-1)^2 which I know is 1), then if a or b is a negative number $a^{p}\cdot b^{p}\neq(a\cdot b)^{p}$, I want to know why.

Comment: You did, $-1^2=-1$ $(-1)^2=1$.

Comment: @Jose, what you are doing with $-1^2$ is that you are only squaring the one, but leaving the $-$ untouched, the parentheses ensure that you capture all of $(-1)$

Comment: @Aleksandar $-1(-1)^2=-1(1)=-1$, I don't understand how I'm wrong here.

Comment: Ya you're right but what you have there is $(-1)^3=(-1)(-1)(-1)=(-1)(-1)^2$.

Comment: Hmmmm, I see, now that's interesting, I'll give it some thought. Thanks for the input, sorry if I come across as a hardheaded person :p